# keep mysql frame when piping to file?

Tags: mysql, bash

I had a question for mySQL/bash. here's my basic situation

```
****> mysql -u**** -p*** -h*** -P*** -e "SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE password='*0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8'"
+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| user         | host | password                                  |
+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| *********    | %    | *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8 |
| ************ | %    | *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8 |
| *******      | %    | *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8 |
+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------+


****> mysql -u**** -p*** -h*** -P*** -e "SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE password='*0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8'" >test.tmp; more test.tmp 
user    host    password
*********        %       *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8
************     %       *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8
*******    %       *0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8
```

When I output to console, I get a nice, even frame, What can I do to have this frame carry over to when I write it to a file? This is going to be part of a much larger script. I know it would be possible to re-create the frame with awk, but I'm hoping there's a simple was to have it carry over. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-t` option to explicitly output a table:

```
mysql -u**** -p*** -h*** -P*** -t -e "SELECT ..." > text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql -u**** -p*** -h*** -P*** --tab -e "SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE password='*0F7947B374392A8F5638B396E0E4BB198D1D16D8'" >test.tmp
```

Note the --tab